# How to model endpoint with different data types?

Tags: json, rest, endpoint

I have a model in the DB with the following structure

- id
- key
- value_type (can be 'String', 'Integer' and 'Boolean')
- string_value
- int_value
- bool_value

Where only one of `string_value`, `int_value` or `bool_value` have value while the other 2 are nulls depends on the value of `value_type`. for example:

```
id:1, key:'key1', value_type:'String', string_value:'random string', int_value:null, bool_value: null  
id:2, key:'key2', value_type:'Integer', string_value:NULL, int_value:777, bool_value:NULL   
id:3, key:'key3', value_type:'Boolean', string_value:NULL, int_value:NULL, bool_value:false
```

I want to open an endpoint to allow GET for entities of this type and consider the two following JSON structure for the return object:

Option 1:

```
{
    id:<id>,
    key:<key>,
    value_type:<value_type>,
    value:<a string representation of the value>
}
```

for instance:

```
{
    id:2,
    key:"key2",
    value_type:"Integer",
    value:"777"
}
```

Option 2:

```
{
    id:<id>,
    key:<key>,
    value_type:<value_type>,
    string_value:<string_value>,
    integer_value:<integer_value>,
    boolean_value:<boolean_value>
}
```

for instance:

```
{
    id:2,
    key:"key2",
    value_type:"Integer",
    string_value:null,
    integer_value:777
    boolean_value:null
}
```

The first option is cleaner while the second one is more typesafe. Is there any standard or consideration to take before making a choice?

Comment: Is it necessary to send along the type info? JSON already has that baked in: literals true and false are booleans, literals surrounded with double quotes are strings, and numeric literals are of type number. Just curious if that would work for your use case.

Comment: @RichardGieg - the idea is that if in the future I will have more data-types. the client won't have to check each if field if it has value, it will know where to look for it.